# Protocol agnostic image transform url's

Tags: ssl

I have one page under `https://` how do I deliver the images there via `https`? Whith the whole site under `https` it's easy via `environmentVariables` but what if there is just one secure page?

Is there a realtive url transform variable? Or do I need to set a separate `environmentVariables` just for the assets on this page?

Comment: Either that or couldn't you just setup an htaccess rule for that page and all of its resources to be served over https?

Comment: Okay. So I have to steer this with .htaccess not with craft at all. Thanks for clearing that up.